# conditional pattern in preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

I try to replace a word with `preg_replace` as

```
preg_replace('/(word)[\W|\.]/', 'NEW', $str);
```

instead of matching and replacing the world, it replaced `(word)[\W|\.]`. How can I adjust the pattern to replace `word` only?

Comment: `'/word(?=[\W.])/'`. I doubt you need to match a `|` char, so I suggest removing it.

Comment: `.` is already included in `\W`.